# I want to put in one row several rows of the same column depending on the characteristics of another column. Any suggestions on how to do that in R?

Tags: r

[image: df1 and df2]

I have one df1 and I want to merge certain rows of specific columns based on the names of another column

Answer (score 1):

An option is `aggregate` by specifying a formula with the `rhs` specifying the grouping column ('Name') and `.` for all the others ('Likes', 'How many hrs spend liking') and `paste` them together

```
aggregate(. ~ Name, df1, FUN = toString)
```

Comment: If you use the vector function `c` as your FUN you can keep the class of each column.

Comment: @DanielO It would return a `list` column.  Not sure if the OP wants that

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! What do you mean by rhs? So you mean it would be: 
df2 <- aggregate(Likes ~ Name, df1, FUN= toString) 
The next would be
df3<- aggregate(How many hrs spend liking ~ Name, df1, FUN= toString)
final_df <- cbind(df2,df3)

Comment: @mk894 It means each of the columns are individually aggregated by Name with that single command.